# Why the shift in Ned Land's character?

Tags: character, 20000-leagues-under-the-sea

In the film [*20,000 Leagues Under the Sea* (1954)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046672/), Kirk Douglas' character Ned Land is seen as a "cocky master harpooner" [­¹].  However, over the course of the film he appears more childlike than cocky, at least to me.  Did Disney remove the "edge" from this character to make him more likable/less intimidating?

[¹] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20,000_Leagues_Under_the_Sea_(1954_film)#Plot